# Error: structure exists in two different assemblies

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms App built on net standard 2.1.
In the class library (the shared code) and and on the line

```
bmp.SetPixel(j,i, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'Color' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

The following despendencies exist:
Assemblies references System.Drawing.Common
and
Frameworks references NetStandard.Library (V2.1.0)

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: I did not find the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6) with version 4.0.0.0, can you try to update this nuget package and try again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6) to solve the structure exists in two different assemblies error.